# How to click on CTRL+M (Control + M) in WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, appium, webdriver-io

I have to issue a **CTRL+M** action in WebdriverIO, but it is not working.

I have tried using different ways such as:

- `browser.keys('Control').keys('m');`
- `browser.keys(['Control','KeyM', 'NULL']);`
- `browser.keys(['Control', 'm', 'NULL']);`
- `browser.keys('Control').keys('KeyM');`
- `browser.deviceKeyEvent(82); browser.pressKeycode(82); browser.keys('MENU');`

None of the above are working. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `I have to click on control+M` you want to click on some keystrokes?

Comment: yes.but here the mobile keyboard is not present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, **NO**. You *currently* cannot chain key commands with any driver configuration. `.keys()` does in fact still work with `chromedriver`(only sending text, no chaining), yet it has been marked for deprecation. See list bellow for more details.

`Dependencies:`

```
"selenium-standalone": "^5.11.2",
"wdio-selenium-standalone-service": "0.0.8",
"webdriverio": "4.8.0"
```

`Driver versions affected:`

```
ChromeDriver: 2.29-x64-chromedriver
GeckoDriver:  0.16.0-x64-geckodriverIEDriver:
3.4.0-x64-IEDriverServer
```

What is wrong with the `.keys()` command?

- this is a known issue throughout the Selenium community and won't be fixed/tackled in WebdriverIO until the drivers (`chromedriver`, `geckodriver`, etc.) implement Webdriver's new W3C standard for user input, [*Actions API*](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#actions);
- there is not other way of doing this (*trust me, I tried!*), unless you can actually substitute the functionality of your `CTRL + M` action via code;
- here is a [BUG](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2611) that documents this issue for GeckoDriver (Firefox);
- even if the `.keys()` method is working with your current version, Christian-Bromann confirmed it will be *deprecated* in the next release (it is also marked for deprecation in the `/lib/protocol/keys.js` definition file).

**Note:** For anyone having similar issues with different WDIO commands, the deprecation of `.keys()`(WDIO), `.sendKeys()`(WebdriverJS) also applies to other broken WebdriverIO methods like `.moveTo()`. Read more about it [*here*](https://gist.github.com/maggiesavovska/760ce97ca2c0dd60367c1cb83d10fd72).

Comment: @Payal, what is the behavior triggered by the `CTRL+M` command? Anyways you should find a workaround via code. Consider accepting the answer so it becomes visible to other users struggling with this issue.

Comment: Actually, I am clicking on first button.Then I have to click on CTRL+M... after that, I have to click on second button.So after clicking on first button, it is not clicking on CTRL+M and searching for second button.As it is not present,so it is displaying the error as 'cannot find the element using given locator' after timeout.

Comment: @Payal Yes, unfortunately chaining keys in **WebdriverIO** is not possible right now as per my above response. You can still try to *emulate* the `CTRL+M` command via code (via `.execute()`). What does `CTRL+M` try to achieve in your test? (e.g.: open a file, close a window, select some text)

Comment: In my emulator, it is not displaying the logout button of application which is present on the real device.So in manual testing,if I click the CTRL+M,after clicking the first button,it gives me the popup for logout button in emulator.Then clicking on confirm logout button,my task ends. Butwhile performing automation, it is not clicking on CTRL+M.

Comment: @iamdanchiv I am on WDIO5 has something changed? Need to paste with CTRL+V